# как мне перемножить числа в print()

Tags: python, print

```py
result = []

while True:
    item = int(input())
    if item == 0:
        break
    result.append(item)

print("*".join(map(str, result)))

for result in range(0):
        print(-1)
```

у меня такой код и в ответ выводит(например)

`1*2*3*4`

а я хочу, чтобы они и в правду перемножилиcь, как это сделать?

Comment: до цикла создаете переменную, в цикле умножаете ее на следующее число, после цикла выводите.

Comment: ну так надо и перемножить, а не превращать в строку с * между символами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы правильно начали, что собираете все входные данные от пользователя в список `result`

Проблема в том, что семантика метода `.join` такова, что она складывает **строки** из какой-то коллекции с (или без) разделительного знака

В вашем случае вы используете `*`.

Вы прогоняете список входных данных (в вашем случае - чисел), через функцию преобразования в число, а перед `.join`, весь набор преобразуете обратно в строки

Если вы хотите функционально перемножить ваш набор, используйте функцию `reduce` из пакета `functools`. Первым аргументом в нее нужно передать [лямбда выражение](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda), которое опишет, как будет происходить "слияние" ваших элементов.

```py
from functools import reduce

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = arr.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, arr)
print(result) # Выведет 120
```

Можно использовать императивный подход и явно описать аккумуляцию

```py
arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
result = arr[0]
for element in arr[1:]:
  result *= element
```

Так-же можно сразу инициализировать `result` и использовать подход, предложенный в комментариях

Answer (score 1):

Можно умножать сразу в while и потом вывести результат:

```
multiply = 1
while True:
    item = int(input())
    if item == 0:
        break
    multiply *= item

print(multiply)
```